# PHP - calling a constant from inside a string

Tags: php, string, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include constant in string without concatenating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203943/include-constant-in-string-without-concatenating)

Hi

I saw you can call call variables inside strings like this: `$X = "bla bla $variable";`
Can I also do this with constants, and if I can, what's the synthax?

Comment: thanks that answers my questions. so there's no way to do this

Comment: I like the answers to the linked question... they're amusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible to do that by default. It might be possible to write a function to parse the string, but why would you want to do that :P

Answer (score 7):

You can't call it inside strings, so you have to type `$X = "bla bla " . constant`.

If you really really wanted to call it from inside a string, then you'd have to use the get_defined_constants function :

```
$consts = get_defined_constants();
echo "bla bla {$consts['constant']}";
```

But really, there's no point ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

`$X = "bla bla" . CONSTANT_NAME;`

Comment: but it's not really inside the string :)

Comment: Well, it kinda is. We use string concatenation, but I guess you want it to be inside quotes.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the command interpolation trick:

```
$php = "htmlspecialchars";
# or = function ($s) {return $s}

$string = "bla bla {$php(constant('CNAME')} bla";
$string = "but just {$php(CONSTANT_NAME)} should also work";
```