# How to have constants evaluated in strings?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include constant in string without concatenating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203943/include-constant-in-string-without-concatenating)

How can I get a constant to be evaluated in a string like variables are?

```
$foo = "like";
define('BAR', 'fish');

// None of these give me 'I like to eat fish on Tuesday.'
echo "I $foo to eat BAR on Tuesday.";
echo "I $foo to eat {BAR} on Tuesday.";
echo 'I $foo to eat BAR on Tuesday.';

// This works but is undesirable
echo 'I $foo to eat '.BAR.' on Tuesday.';
```

Comment: Not sure it's possible but you could define a variable and use that to replace it?

Comment: Undesirable, but necessary. Buck up. (different Andrew!)

Comment: This has been covered several times on SO, just worded a bit differently (which is why you didn't see it when asking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know that isn't possibile. Check this answer here at SO, it contains useful workarounds if concatenation is so undesirable too you! [Include constant in string without concatenating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203943/include-constant-in-string-without-concatenating)

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know this'd works (which you may already be aware of) is by doing:

```
<?php
$foo = "like";
define('BAR', 'fish');
$constants = get_defined_constants();
echo "I $foo to eat {$constants['BAR']} on Tuesday.";
?>
```

which prints:

```
I like to eat fish on Tuesday.
```

Comment: I was aware, but thank you for the reassurance.  I considered this option but it ended up reducing the code readability.

Comment: Not only does it reduce code readability but it also prevents the IDE  from detecting invalid constants in your string.

Answer (score -2):

of course there is no way. And no need.

Comment: -1 There's no explanation to your answer, just judgement.

Comment: @Andrew there's no explanation to your question either. just "undesirable" judgement ;)

Comment: I'm surprised that someone with a 19k rep would post such a useless answer... Actually after looking at your profile, it seems your approach of being two steps ahead leads to a lot of condescending answers.

Comment: @Juan did you happen to read the question? :)

Comment: I did. "How to have constants evaluated within strings". The reason I downvoted was that I actually find that it would be useful to be able to do "Select {MY_COLUMN_CONSTANT} from {MY_TABLE_CONSTANT} WHERE {OTHER_COLUMN} = :value" instead of harcoding constant names everywhere. Now I either have to do string concatenation, which makes it hard to read, or I have to copy the constants to local variables...

Comment: Oh, I am blamed for some PHP feature, lol :)

Comment: Nobody is blaming you for the lack of this feature in PHP. Just not happy with your condescending comment/answer that there is no need for this. "There is no way" is accurate, but "no need" is your point of view, trying to see two steps ahead.